# Noob Syntax help: How to global replace characters in a string using an indexed substring e.g. text[i]?

Tags: javascript, replace

In this problem, I would like to find the number of distinct characters (case-insensitive).
I understand there are other approaches to the problem, but my current approach is to identify the first character in the `text` string and remove all equivalent characters globally, +1 to the counter and rinse and repeat  for all remaining chars. Looking at the JS docs online, I  can't seem to figure out how to make this work, I figured someone could teach me how to do the regular expression for this. Thanks.

```
let text = "aAabbbacccaaade";
text = text.replace(text[0]/gi,"");

// text = text.replace(/text[0]/gi,""); => aAabbbacccaaade
// text = text.replace(text[0]/gi,""); => gi is undefined error.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your regex using the `new` constructor and a string argument:

```js
let text = "aAabbbacccaaade";
console.log(text);

let regex = new RegExp(text[0], "gi");
text = text.replace(regex,"");
console.log(text);
```

Looping this should work for your method:

```js
const text = "aAabbbacccaaade";

function countUnique(str) {
  let mutableStr = str;
  let count = 0;
  while (mutableStr.length > 0) {
    let r = new RegExp(mutableStr[0], "gi");
    mutableStr = mutableStr.replace(r, "");
    count++;
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(countUnique(text));
```

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to ask any questions, and if you think this is a suitable answer then please mark it as such.